# Notepad++ remain Regular expression text

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a text which looks like below. I only want to remain texts, which are matched by this expression: `:label=\w+`

```
SELECT
R.ResourceName AS @header :name="Carrier" :label=SelVal_Carrier :datatype=String
, C.ContainerName AS @header :name="Lot" :label=WebUI_Lot :datatype=String
, C.Qty AS @header :name="Qty" :label=SelVal_Qty :datatype=Fixed
, C.Qty2 AS @header :name="Qty2" :label=SelVal_Qty2 :datatype=Fixed
```

Comment: Have you tried something? What is your expected output?

Comment: delete all the text, only remain :label=xxxxx

Comment: yes i'm tried. when using expression :label=\w+ it able to mark all the label but i'm not sure how to delete the least of the word

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>

Find what: `.*?(:label=\w+ ).*`
Replace with: `$1`

Comment: i want to remain all the text which is :label=\w+

Comment: Did you try Totos answer? Did it work? The $1 captures the part matched by the regexp in the parentheses. So the Find is the whole line with the label part captured in $1and the replacement is $1, only the label part of the line.